# How to force RAM to program?

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, cmd, command

I am about to make batch program, and then compile it with BAT to EXE converter.
If I am making program like

```
@echo off
set Line=0
:Start
set /a Line=%Line% + 1
echo %Line%
goto :Start
```

I see each time, previous number, +1.

This goes quite fast, but I can still follow sequence.

I know that computers are thousands times faster, since they have to calculate much much more for computer itself.

Is there possibility to force additional performance for program? Reserving RAM, or anything like it?

Comment: It won't make any difference.  99.9% of the execution time is spent in the echo command.  Writing to the console is very slow.  And doesn't get faster when you use compiled code.  It doesn't matter that the console is slow, it was meant for human eyes.  Make it faster by only writing to the console, say, every 1000 times.

Answer (score 3):

code, you can test:

```
@echo off & SETLOCAL
for /l %%i in (0) do <nul set/p=.
```

---

```
@echo off & SETLOCAL
:loop
SET /a var+=1
ECHO %var%
goto:loop
```

Comment: First code results dots... I tried change code to
`for /l %%i in (0) do <nul set /a=var+=1`
But it says it's missing operand..., and how the heck does that increase performance, it does increase print performance, but it was just example. I have big files of batch files which I need to execute...

Answer (score 1):

You can make it about a million times faster by using a real programming language.

In batch, you are actually executing plain text commands, which are individually parsed and executed by the command interpreter. This was never optimized for speed. A batch to exe convertor does little more than wrap the code of a batch file and feed it to the command interpreter, so it doesn't execute any (or at least not much) faster than a regular batch file.

Extra RAM doesn't mean extra performance by the way. Extra RAM only gives you extra performance if your application has too little RAM available to fit all its data in. If that happens, a part of your application's memory is swapped to disk, causing an extra performance hit. 
But there's not much you can do about that in batch anyway.

Many programming languages have compilers which convert your code to actual machine instructions, or at least instructions for a highly optimized virtual machine, like .NET or JVM. Even scripting languages like PHP are highly optimized, because they need to be able to execute large chunks of code in very little time. 
For batch, this is not the case. You're just missing the purpose of what batch is, which is repeating a lot of command line instructions, because you don't want to have to type them in every time. ;-)

Comment: I know only Batch, for such language. Is there really no solution for this?

Comment: I'm afraid not, although part of the slowdown is displaying the number. Screen IO is always quite instensive. If you'd display the number only once every 10 iterations, you may notice that it runs actually faster. But then again, you've also changed the output of your program, which is not always an option. 
But although Batch is great (I've even written a game in it once), it may be time to move to something else. :)

Comment: Is there any "programming" language that works as batch? That could be compiled and easily started from any computer.

Comment: Not exactly the same, although many are similar. I think closest to Batch you'll find Basic or Pascal, but I'd rather learn C# instead. But that's something you'll have to find out for yourself, also depending on your wants and needs. And for some problems, batch may still be the best solution. :)